# Confirmar inscrição de email em um tópico SNS de forma automatizada

Tags: java, amazon-aws, push-notification, sns

Utilizo o serviço SNS em uma aplicação, é feito o seguinte processo:

Usuário informa sua localização, e se não houver a cidade inserida no banco é criado um registro na tabela quanto a cidade e criado um tópico no SNS, certo? Depois o usuário com seu e-mail é inscrito nesse tópico, porém, o mesmo precisa confirmar a inscrição em uma mensagem de e-mail enviada pela AWS para conseguir receber as publicações. Tem alguma maneira de automatizar isso e utililizando a AWS SDK ou outro meio já confirmar a inscrição?

Vi que utilizando o console da AWS tem como passando uma URL, mas ainda não encontrei outro meio.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Referências:

[AWS Push Notification Service](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/sns/)

[Amazon Simple Notification Service - Developer Guide](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/SNS/latest/sns-dg.pdf)